# Is there a convention for receiving HBITMAPs from a STA COM object and giving them back?

Tags: winapi, com

Okay, so now I want to create a COM interface that represents the data model my custom table control will take, instead of using messages passed between the table and its parent window. The table currently displays text, images, and checkboxes. Objects that implement the interface are expected to live in single-thread apartments.

I know I can use `BSTR`s for strings and some integer type for the checkbox booleans, and that there are already established conventions for ownership transfer for these that I can follow. But I'm not sure about bitmaps.

What I want to do is call the model object's `GetCellData()` method, which takes the row, column, and a pointer to a `VARIANT` that the model will put the cell's data in. I only need to draw the bitmap once before disposing of it. [Since bitmaps can only be selected into one DC at a time](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/06/10399678.aspx), I need to be the exclusive owner of the bitmap, but only temporarily.

I tried looking for a similar COM interface by Microsoft that did this already, but didn't find anything (or didn't look using the right terms).

So my questions are:

1. How would I pass the `HBITMAP` into the `VARIANT`? My best guess is storing it in the `byref` field.
2. How should I negotiate ownership of the `HBITMAP`? I see two possibilities: either a) require a copy of the `HBITMAP` to be sent each time, with the table control itself calling `DeleteObject()`, or b) have the `HBITMAP` borrowed (use it and then have another model method `FinishedWithBitmap()` that will be called when finished). Is any one of these more suited to COM's rules than the other? Or do I have the wrong idea entirely? Would `STGMEDIUM` be appropriate?

I should point out the `HBITMAP`s are treated as 32-bit ARGB (that is, they're drawn by `AlphaBlend()`). I found `IPicture` but that doesn't seem appropriate for this format.

Thanks.

**Update**

Okay here's the general idea. Let's say `model` is the table model, which is the server. The table itself is the client. The code for drawing a bitmap cell in the client would look like this:

```
HBITMAP bitmap;

ITableModel_GetCellData(model, row, column, &bitmap);
// draw the bitmap (CreateCompatibleDC(), SelectObject(), AlphaBlend())
```

At this point the client doesn't need `bitmap` anymore. I'm asking if COM has a canonical way of defining the ownership of the `HBITMAP` to the client's drawing code, so I as the client author would know if I should either write

```
// the client owns the bitmap
DeleteObject(bitmap);
```

or

```
// the model still owns bitmap
// we need to explicitly give it back because only one DC can have a bitmap selected at one time
// since each client has the DCs, the server needs to know when it's safe to give the same HBITMAP to another client
ITableModel_ReturnBitmap(model, bitmap);
```

(IDataObject provides a solution to this problem in the form of `STGMEDIUM.pUnkForRelease`.)

Comment: Look into IDataObject.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson hm... are you suggesting I should have my `GetCellData()` method return `IDataObject`s then? In that case, only for bitmaps or for the other types as well? And what if the model object doesn't want to copy the `HBITMAP`; does it have any recourse there? (Unless there is a way to copy `HBITMAP`s that I don't know about...)

Comment: Your title says you want to *receive* a bitmap, but then your question is: how would you *pass* the bitmap. Can you clarify - did you mean, how would users of your object pass their bitmap? Also it is not clear whether your code supposed to modify the bitmap received and return the changes to the caller.

Comment: @MattMcNabb does the update to the question help explain what's going on?

Comment: In IDataObject::GetData() you pass the data in a STGMEDIUM and the caller is responsible for freeing it.  There is a standard API, ReleaseStgMedium() that the caller can call to free bitmaps or whatever else you can pass in a STGMEDIUM.

Comment: @andlabs not really, sorry :( is the client or the server calling ITableModel_GetCellData ?  It would be good to clearly distinguish in your post between client and server operations; you seem to be using "I" for both

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson right. Actually thinking about it, in the case of not copying the `HBITMAP` I could just provide a dummy `IUnknown` implementation for `STGMEDIUM.pUnkForRelease` that sets a flag that the bitmap is no longer selected (and then the question of how to clone an `HBITMAP` is an unrelated question)... which I guess answers that question; thanks.

Comment: @MattMcNabb how about now? Sorry if this is still confusing :/

Comment: @andlabs so the client calls GetCellData to retrieve a bitmap from the server, which the client then draws; and you're envisaging that the server will unselect the bitmap from its DC, when the client request comes in; and then wait for the client to report that the client is done with it?  Also - is uding VARIANT a requirement or was that just an idea?

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson the other thing is that IDataObject seems to be far more persistent than what I would need, including providing provisions for notifying on changes (my model itself has a Subscribe() method for doing that, for instance) and setting values (which I plan on providing in a separate derived interface)...

Comment: @MattMcNabb no, the client needs to unselect the bitmap from its DC and then tell the server that it did so, so that the server is free to give the same bitmap to another client; VARIANT is an idea, based on my limited knowledge of COM/OLE

Comment: That's what I meant by "report that the client is done with it"

Comment: You don't have to implement every method fully.  If you want, for those you don't want to implement, just return E_NOTIMPL. It's my recommendation after many years of Windows development.  Good luck.  Time for bed.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Of course. Part of the reason I asked is that IIRC the Windows API doesn't have a `DuplicateBitmap()` function (and to make it worse, `GetObject()` and `CreateDIBSection()` require different data structures). I could be wrong, and/or I could just provide this myself. Whatever the case, it seems it's either this or IDataObject; I'm in control of all this so I have all the time I need to decide. Thanks to both of you so far...

Comment: COM doesn't know how to marshal HBITMAP anyway. Are you planning to implement marshaling? (would be useful for DCOM , although apparently a HBITMAP can be used as-is by any process on the same PC so long as it was created in the right way).  If it will never actually need to be marshaled then you could just pass it like an integer.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if I'm going to support marshaling yet (or if so, how to go about doing so); since this is for my custom control I was imagining everything being in-process for now (I don't know of any other GUI toolkit that also uses the table model-table view paradigm that allows out-of-process data models to begin with, so...). The custom control is in a DLL, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I decided to take a different approach for now: rather then returning an HBITMAP to draw, I provide a method that takes the HDC and have the model do the drawing. (The DLL will provide a helper implementation for people who do write custom models.) Other COM interfaces (like IImageList) do this already, so why not :/

I'm not sure if I'll keep the `GetCellData()` method as it is or break it apart into one function for each data type. Another column type I just realized I would need for the model is `COLORREF` (for customizing cell background colors; model columns and view columns are not equivalent). I'm also not sure what I'll do about a `SetCellData()` method in the same vein; it'll only be used by the Table view itself when the user decides to change something int he UI (by checking a checkbox, for instance) and I don't think I'll provide a way to change images directly from within the table, so... Adding separate model functions for each different data type would obviously be a poor idea (especially if interfaces have to remain constant once finalized), but `VARIANT` is looking less and less optimal.

Answer (score 0):

That is certainly one way.  The beauty of implementing IDataObject is that the consumer of the object can decide on what format he requires--of course you have to say what you will provide.  But, with delay rendering, you can wait until they actually request the data before you provide it.